# Duplicity Incremental Restores

Tags: linux, backup, incremental-backup, duplicity

I use duplicity to manage an encrypted daily incremental and weekly full backup schedule for my Linux box. Though duplicity allows incremental backups, I could not find any way to do anything other than a full restore.

I'm running a 2nd server where I restore the duplicity backup, but I want to keep this 2nd server in sync with the original server through the duplicity backups. The only way that's happening now is if I remove all files on the 2nd server and do a full restore through duplicity every time which is wasteful and slow.

Is there no way to do an "incremental restore" in duplicity which only updates changed files in the restore destination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want to be using Duplicity to keep your second server up to date with your primary. This is why rsync exists and would suit your needs perfectly.

Comment: I disagree with the "want" part. If I'm already using an rsync-based protocol to sync changes in an encrypted, incremental fashion to a remote server, I would WANT to reduce the redundant bandwidth / CPU usage on my production server in repeating the whole process for a backup to a different server (albeit in a slightly different form). The question is whether or not duplicity supports this behavior, or as an added plus if it's planned in the future (I see no mention of it in their mailing lists)

Comment: I understand what you're saying. Could you do something like having prodserver rsync to devserver and then use Duplicity to backup from devserver?

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: I guess the answer to the original question is that duplicity does in fact not have this feature.

Comment: Asad, have you tried this option? The -t allows you to specify to Duplicity to only restore after a certain time. Here's an example:
`duplicity -t 2010-09-22T01:10:00 s3+http://com.mycorp.myhost.backup ~/restore`